# Compare page in Magnolia CMS gives: The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: java, magnolia

When I tried to use the function compare pages in my Magnolia CMS 5.7 I'm receiving an error saying this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 51; The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 51; The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 51; The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.
    info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:234)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:89)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:77)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.security.CsrfSecurityFilter.doFilter(CsrfSecurityFilter.java:106)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.multisite.filters.MultiSiteFilter.doFilter(MultiSiteFilter.java:120)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.enterprise.registration.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:64)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:111)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:110)
    info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:96)
```

This is also happening with pages which contains just a single text "test" and after change to "test123".

I understand that it cannot parse the pages I want to compare to valid xml so it can compare them, but I have no clue what to look after for, so any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There something wrong with one of your components put on the template. Suggestion: in component html remove all serverside code and put some static content. Additional disable corresponding dialog. Going step by step to find out whene your error message will raise. Keep all things simple.

Comment: Isn't there more info in the log file? Also what compare function do you mean? Compare versions of same page provided by diff module or something custom developed for your project?